# detect exception - if

Tags: php, exception

If i have this:

```
function valid($valor) {
        foreach($valor as $valor){
            if (!empty($valor)) {
                if (preg_match("/[^A-Za-z0-9-áàçéúâôóã ]|(\d+)/", $valor)) {
                    $error = "invalid";
                    throw new Exception($error);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and

```
if (isset($_POST['myform'])){
    if ($val_->valid($form1['new'])) {
        echo "ok";
    }
    else 
        echo "bad";
}
```

but i got: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception`

What i want is basically something like that (pseudo code):

```
if (exception true) {
    echo "problem";
}
else
    echo "ok";
```

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to handle the [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php).

```
try {
    ...
    //statements
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

EDIT:

```
 try{
   if ($val_->valid($form1['new'])) {
     echo "ok";
    }
  }catch(Exception $e){   
     echo "bad";
   }
```

Comment: the problem is that i need personalized messages. I am using the same function for different content.

Comment: Yes, this was instead of your pseudocode. `try { valid($foo); echo "ok"; } catch (Exception $e) { echo "problem"; }` would be a direct rewrite.